# Write java objects to CSV file

Tags: java, csv, serialization

I have a project over data structures I am working on. I have a LinkedList and I need to be able to save object data to a text file

"Create a text file that is a list of last name, first name, and email address. You may use CSV or any other delimiter"

When I try to save the object data I get this "¬í t John" instead of just "John"

My class(main and student, and email) implements Serializable

```
public class Main implements Serializable
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
    Date date = new Date();

    Email e1 = new Email("js@got.com");
    Email e2 = new Email("doge@me.me");
    Email e3 = new Email("admin@microvern.com");
    Student s1 = new Student("John", "Snow", e1);
    Student s2 = new Student("Shiba", "Inu", e2);
    Student s3 = new Student("Vern", "Vern", e3);
    Student s4 = new Student("Professor", "Messer", new Email("pm@cs.net"));
    ListInterface<Student> linkedList = new LinkedList<Student>();
    linkedList.add(s1, 2); //should be pos 3
    linkedList.add(s2, 3); //should be pos 4
    linkedList.add(s3, 1); // should be pos 2
    linkedList.add(s4, 1); //should be pos 1
    System.out.println(linkedList);
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("students.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        output.writeObject(s1.getfirstName());
        output.close();
        fos.close();
        System.out.println("Data saved in /file/students.txt");
    } 
    catch (IOException exc) 
        {
        System.out.println("Failed to write to file!");
        exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The short answer is, you don't want to use an `ObjectOutputStream`

Comment: This is the second question of that csv topic within 20 minutes. Is there a major homework or test running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write into a `CSV` file then you don't need to implement `Serializable` interface. With Serialization you can not write `csv` file. Serialization process write object state into .`sar` file. You may consider to use some `CSV` library or you may write it. You may check [this tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/writeread-csv-files-in-java-example/).